# Show information according to selected row

Tags: javascript, html, css

According to the selected row, it should show the information of that product on the right side, so far I have done this:

```js
document.querySelector("table tbody tr").addEventListener('click', (e) =>{

  let elem = document.querySelector(".loremDiv");
  if(elem.classList.contains('show')){
    elem.classList.remove('show');
    elem.classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    elem.classList.add('show');
    elem.classList.remove('hidden');
  }

});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  }
.container div {
  flex: 1;
  }
.show {
  display: flex;
  }
.hidden {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>01</td>
          <td>Acoustic Guitar</td>
          <td>[delete] [edit]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>02</td>
          <td>Box of Milk</td>
          <td>[delete] [edit]</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div  class="loremDiv hidden">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    Est asperiores sed a repellat error, temporibus at maxime libero, 
    praesentium adipisci veritatis quam, accusantium sequi laborum minus 
    impedit et quasi dolor.
  </div>
</div>
```

If, for example, there is a row 02 and the product is a box of milk, when selecting it, it must show its respective image and title on the right side. In the same way if the product is a guitar or another.

I also want there to be a transition when the information is hidden or shown. The problem that occurs is that when I select a row and then select a different row, the information is hidden and what I want is for the information to change.

demo:

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qxL9o1bw/1/)

Comment: You have mentioned that `when you select another row`, But in your code you have click event only on button.  It means you have the button on each row or how user will select row and then click button?

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. It is when a row is selected, the information for that row should be displayed.  I modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my sample code:

```js
let productList = {
  "01": {
    "productDesc": "guitar",
    "productImg": "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/acoustic-guitar-picture-id173240169?s=612x612"
  },
  "02": {
    "productDesc": "milk",
    "productImg": "https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/08/which-milk-is-right-for-you-700-350-c7cdd0e.jpg?webp=true&quality=90&resize=385%2C350"
  },
}
let fadeState = "I";
let key = "01",
  oldKey = "01";
let productDesc = document.getElementById("productDesc");
let product = productList[key];
productDesc.innerHTML = "Product Name:" + product.productDesc + "<br>";
productDesc.innerHTML += "<img src=\"" + product.productImg + "\">";

productDesc.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  let product = productList[key];
  switch (fadeState) {
    case "O":
      productDesc.classList.add("hidden");
      productDesc.classList.remove("fadeOut");
      productDesc.innerHTML = "Product Name:" + product.productDesc + "<br>";
      productDesc.innerHTML += "<img src=\"" + product.productImg + "\">";
      productDesc.classList.remove("hidden");
      fadeState = "I";
      productDesc.classList.add("fadeIn");
      break;
    case "I":
      productDesc.classList.remove("fadeIn");
  }
});
document.querySelectorAll(".product").forEach(productRow => {
  productRow.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    key = productRow.cells[0].textContent;
    if (key != oldKey) {
      oldKey = key;
      product = productList[key];
      if (productDesc.innerHTML == "") {
          productDesc.innerHTML = "Product Name:" + product.productDesc + "<br>";
            productDesc.innerHTML += "<img src=\"" + product.productImg + "\">";
            fadeState = "I";
            productDesc.classList.add("fadeIn");
      } else {
        fadeState = "O";
        productDesc.classList.add("fadeOut");
      }
    } else {
      productDesc.innerHTML = "";
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}

.container div{
  flex: 1;
}

.show{
  display: flex;
}

.hidden{
  display: none;
}

.fadeIn{
 animation: fadeIn 5s;
}

.fadeOut{
 animation: fadeOut 5s;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {opacity:1;}
  100% {opacity:0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="product">
          <td>01</td>
          <td>Acoustic Guitar</td>
          <td>[delete] [edit]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="product">
          <td>02</td>
          <td>Box of Milk</td>
          <td>[delete] [edit]</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="productDesc" class="loremDiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And if I select row again, how could I hide the information again?

With the code I show, could you add a transition? I have tried and it does not work for me.

Comment: In the beginning, you selected guitar, do you mean when you select milk, the product description would be fade out first and then show the milk product description?

Comment: Yes, but also when it is pressed for the first time. In addition, when the same row is pressed, nothing is displayed.

Comment: Do you mean when the same row is pressed, the product description div keep unchanged?

Comment: Sorry, my english is not good.

2 click (same product) => show empty.    

Maybe that's how you understand me.

Comment: Is it possible to use the jQuery library?

Comment: No problem, although I wish it was with Vanilla JS.

Comment: I have updated my code for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code for you. You might want to give it a try.

```js
const productDetailsContainer = document.querySelector('.product-details-container');
const productDetails = document.querySelector('.product-details');

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".table-row")).forEach(row => {
    row.addEventListener("click", e => {

        const row_tr = e.target.parentNode
        const first_td = Array.from(row_tr.children)[0].textContent; // td element
        const second_td_text = Array.from(row_tr.children)[1].textContent;
        const second_td_img_src = Array.from(row_tr.children)[1].children[0].src;

        const details_div = document.createElement('div')
        const newImg = document.createElement('img');
        newImg.src = second_td_img_src;

        const codigoProducto = document.createElement('div');
        codigoProducto.classList.add("product-title")
        codigoProducto.innerText = "From Codigo Producto: " + first_td

        const nombre = document.createElement('p')
        nombre.innerText = "This is my product: " + second_td_text

        details_div.append(codigoProducto, nombre, newImg)
        details_div.classList.add(`product-${first_td}`, 'details')

        if (productDetails.children.length === 0) {
            productDetails.classList.remove("hidden")
            productDetails.appendChild(details_div)
        } else {
            productDetails.removeChild(productDetails.children[0])
            productDetails.appendChild(details_div)
        }
    })
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container{
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.product-details {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.hidden{
  display: none;
}

.table-row {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
   
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-container">
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>codigo producto</th>
            <th>nombre</th>
            <th>acciones</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="table-row">
            <td>01</td>
            <td>
              guitarra acustica #1
              <img class="hidden" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/C.F._Martin_GRH_160_or_000-16RGT_cropped.png" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>[eliminar] [editar]</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="table-row">
            <td>02</td>
            <td>
              Box of Milk
              <img class="hidden" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/65/62/25/656225106a0f1fd5b12b5d299ac48721.jpg" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>[eliminar] [editar]</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="table-row">
            <td>03</td>
            <td>
              guitarra acustica #3
              <img class="hidden" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71QWkR-IHEL._AC_SY879_.jpg" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>[eliminar] [editar]</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-details-container">
      <div class="product-details hidden">
      </div>
    </div>

  <script src="code.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```